# printing index values in a matrix based on row and column names using awk

Tags: matrix, awk

How can I print index values using awk or others along with 1st row and 1st column ? thanks

```
> input
name s1 s2 s3 s4
g1  2  3  4 5
g2  1  1  1 6
g3  2  2  2 7
g4  2  2  2 10


> output
g1 s1 2
g2 s2 1
g3 s3 2
g4 s4 10
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the `g3 s4` row? What index values? This is very unclear to me.

Comment: its a typo. thanks for pointing it out. I modified it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk to print only the main diagonal values of the matrix

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { split($0,x); next } NF>=NR { print $1,x[NR],$NR }' matrix
g1 s1 2
g2 s2 1
g3 s3 2
g4 s4 10
```

Explained:

```
NR==1 { split($0,x);next }   # split first record to array x for outputing s col
NF>=NR {                     # test for overflow if an asymmerical matrix
    print $1,x[NR],$NR       # output
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

assuming input file is tab separated

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{split($0,h);next} 
                 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,h[i],$i}' file.tsv

g1 s1 2
g1 s2 3
g1 s3 4
g1 s4 5
g2 s1 1
g2 s2 1
g2 s3 1
g2 s4 6
g3 s1 2
g3 s2 2
g3 s3 2
g3 s4 7
```

Comment: It is great thanks. but is it possible to avoid all the pairwise combinations? and just print the values as defined in the output?